# Google Maps, PHP & MySQL: Create multiple markers on map using various options together

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a Google Maps project for the 1st time and I've done a lot of reading and now I need to put it all together.
I have PHP website and a mysql table of locations and I need to show a marker and some info for each location. I have already geocoded the locations so I have latitude & longtitude for each one. I've seen a number of things in the documentation pages but first I'd like to know if I can combine it all in one.

I would like to use the following options:

- [MarkerCluster](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclusterer/1.0/examples/advanced_example.html) for a better display of areas with many near-by markers
- [ClientLocation](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/commonloader/clientlocation.html) for loading the map at the location of the user to show what's nearby
- [Complex Icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex.html) Use custom icons per category
- [Custom InfoWindows](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html)

Also, I'd like to know what is best, to save all locations to an XML or pass them to the API dynamically each time the map is loaded?

Comment: So, erm what exactly is your question? How to put it all together? Why wouldn't you be able to combine them all into one? They're all part of the Google Maps API features. As for the XML, personally I'd use JSON. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

In case you haven't read them already, I think the following articles can help you:

[Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html)

[Creating a Store Locator with PHP & MySQL](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3.html)

[From Info Windows to a Database: Saving User-Added Form Data](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlinfo_v3.html)

Comment: I've read them all, I just wanted to know the best way to go and if all the above can be combined into one map.